# Route for handling all requests except assets in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We are using Laravel 5 and have a route that handles all requests:

```
Route::any('{all}', 'AllController')
        ->where('all', '.*');
```

However this is causing one challenge: it redirects everything including images, JS and CSS.

We would like assets (static content) to be handled by the web server and Laravel to only handle dynamic content. We tried this:

```
Route::any('{all}', 'AllController')
        ->where('all', '.*')->where('all', !=, 'assets/.*');
```

But it gives syntax error `unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL)`.

How can we construct a route that handles everything except assets (static content)?

**Edit: .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have trouble with web server config.. Laravel will handle route only if requested file doesn't exist. In other case web server will return your .css .js without Laravel. For Apache this rules looks like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

UPD: In any case you can using regexp for this

```
Route::any('{all}', 'MyBar@index')->where('all','^((?!assets).)*?');
```

Comment: I have added **.htaccess** file. Looks similar to what you indicate except it has more detail. It's the default as provided by Laravel itself.  We never changed anything.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba Yea, Laravel contain correct `.htaccess` out the box.  Maybe some problem with your main Apache configuration file? Is override allowed here?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by 'override allowed'? But mod_rewrite is enabled on Apache. That's why it handles the Laravel routes. It's possible the problem could be with Apache config but since I don't have enough expertise in  Apache I am trying to handle it from Laravel side. If I remove the 'all requests route' then everything works fine. So, the trick is how to set 'all requests route'  but still ignore assets.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba I've updated my answer. Check it please.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.